# How to install java in NixOS?

Tags: java, nixos

On `NixOS`, I am trying to install  `java` in order to compile my code from the command line.

I do not see the java compiler listed anywhere in the list of available packages, queried by running `nix-env -qaP '*' --description`.

How do I install a java compiler on `NixOS`?

Comment: This page might help: https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html it's a dynamic search page for NixOS' store.

Comment: Searching using a package name usually useless unless you know what you are looking for. Use package page [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403846/how-to-install-java-in-nixos#comment722089_403846) above or add `--description` flag, for example, `nix-env -qaP --description | grep -i java\.*devel`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two Java compilers available via Nixpkgs: OpenJDK and OracleJDK, named `openjdk` and `oraclejdk`, respectively.

Note that the OracleJDK doesn't seem to be available in the top-level expression, but you can certainly install the `openjdk`.

Comment: Thank you. I missed `openjdk` since I had been searching for `java`.